# React - Module not found, For packages inside the installed packages, when requirting express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, npm-install

Hello I tried to install the express package in a react project
But when I import the package inside the app.js using:

```
const app = require("express");
```

I get 30 errors all saying

```
Module not found Error: Can't resolve 'x'
```

where x are differnt packages like `zlib`, `querystring`, `path`, `crypto`, `fs`, `stream` ....

This is the app.js code when I run it without the require line it works fine

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const app = require("express");

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And inside my `package.json` file in my dependencies I do have:     `"express": "^4.17.3"`

I even tried to create a new blank project for this and I had the same problem

Comment: Express is a framework for Node, not React/FE clients. You can't import it like you're doing. You need to set up your own Express server that React interacts with using endpoints/routes.

Answer (score 2):

Your bundler (probably Webpack) cannot bundle packages which depend on Node.js APIs.

Express depends on all sorts of things that need Node.js (such as the ability to listen for incoming HTTP requests and use the C library that zlib uses).

You can't run Express inside a browser.